# Positioning a word at a specified position in word document VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to create a word document from excel. the document has specific text that doesnt vary with some data being entered from excel sheet which is being entered by means of an array. so  whenever this variable data from sheet is entered, the word document adjust the lines as per the length of this variable.  I want to keep the non variable part of my text to be sticking to its specific position regardeless of length of varying data being imported from sheets. Iam also struggling with adjusting the sentence length to match with the paper width. can you  pls help

```
Sub ReminderWordDoc(strValue As String)

Dim wdApp As Word.Application
Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    With wdApp
    .Visible = True
    .Activate
    .Documents.Add
    
Dim objVar As Variant
objVar = Split(strValue, "~")

        With .Selection
            .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight
            .BoldRun 'Switch Bold on
            .Font.Size = 12
            .Font.Name = Arial
            .Font.Underline = wdUnderlineSingle
            .TypeText "IN LIEU OF MSG FORM"
            .TypeParagraph 'Enter a new line
            .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
            .TypeText "PRIORITY"
            .BoldRun 'Switch Bold off
            .TypeParagraph
            .TypeText "FROM: HQ FORT                                                                                        DTG : 02" & vbCrLf
            .TypeText "TO: " + UCase(objVar(1)) + "                                                                                                 UNCLAS" & vbCrLf
            .TypeText "INFO: " + UCase(objVar(2)) + "                                                                                   " + UCase(objVar(1)) & vbCrLf
            .TypeText "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" & vbCrLf
.TypeText " REMINDER NO 1 (.) COMPLAINT IN R/O  " + UCase(objVar(3)) + "  " + UCase(objVar(4)) + "  " + UCase(objVar(2)) + _
            "(.)  REF OUR LETTER NO " + UCase(objVar(0)) + _
            " DT ___________(___) COMMA _______(____) COMMA _______(____)(.) 'R' OF AS ASKED VIDE OUR LETTER UNDER REF IS STILL AWAITED (.) REQUEST FWD THE SAME BY _______ (___) (.) " & vbCrLf
 .TypeText "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" & vbCrLf
            .TypeText "XYZ                              TELE:27676455                                                  SR MGR" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
        
            .TypeText "CASE NO: " + UCase(objVar(0)) + "                                                                                              EXEC " & vbCrLf
            .TypeText "DATED: " + UCase(Date) + "                                                                                                TOR____H" & vbCrLf
        
        End With
        
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Suggest you use a template Word document with placeholders where you need to insert the data from Excel. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/customizing-word/finding-and-replacing-text-or-formatting

Comment: Cant' you use mailmerge for this task?

Comment: Can you post an image of what you expect the document to look like?

Comment: If you want to prevent the layout changing according to the lenghts of your variable content, you would have to insert such content into either a textbox or a table cell with fixed dimensions. In either case, the textbox or a table cell's dimensions would need to be large enought to accommodate the longest variable.

Comment: @macropod .... could you please educate me more on how to  use table cells of fixed dimensions in word document and add text from excel sheet by VBA code ?

Comment: Clearly, you would add the table to your document template *before* running any code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using tables is one way.

```
Sub ReminderWordDoc(strValue As String)

    Dim wdApp As Word.Application
    Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
    
        With wdApp
            .Visible = True
            .Activate
        End With
    Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Add
        
    Dim objVar As Variant
    objVar = Split(strValue, "~")

     With wdApp.Selection
        .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight
        .BoldRun 'Switch Bold on
        .Font.Size = 12
        .Font.Name = Arial
        .Font.Underline = wdUnderlineSingle
        .TypeText "IN LIEU OF MSG FORM"
        .TypeParagraph 'Enter a new line
        .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
        .TypeText "PRIORITY"
        .BoldRun 'Switch Bold off
        .TypeParagraph
     End With
     Dim t1 As Word.Table
     Set t1 = wdDoc.Tables.Add(Range:=wdApp.Selection.Range, NumRows:=9, NumColumns:=2, _
                       DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, _
                       AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitFixed)
                       
     t1.Borders.Enable = False
     w = t1.Rows(1).Cells(1).Width * 2
     w1 = w * 0.75
     w2 = w * 0.25
     
     For x = 1 To 9
         With t1.Rows(x)
             .Cells(1).Width = w1
             .Cells(2).Width = w2
         End With
    Next x
    
    t1.Rows(1).Cells(1).Range.Text = "FROM: HQ FORT"
    t1.Rows(1).Cells(2).Range.Text = "DTG : 02"
    
    t1.Rows(2).Cells(1).Range.Text = "TO: " + UCase(objVar(1))
    t1.Rows(2).Cells(2).Range.Text = "UNCLAS"
    
    t1.Rows(3).Cells(1).Range.Text = "INFO: " + UCase(objVar(2))
    t1.Rows(3).Cells(2).Range.Text = UCase(objVar(1))
    
    t1.Rows(4).Cells.Merge
    t1.Rows(4).Cells(1).Range.Text = String(116, "-")
                       
    t1.Rows(5).Cells.Merge
    t1.Rows(5).Cells(1).Range.Text = " REMINDER NO 1 (.) COMPLAINT IN R/O  " + UCase(objVar(3)) + "  " + UCase(objVar(4)) + "  " + UCase(objVar(2)) + _
         "(.)  REF OUR LETTER NO " + UCase(objVar(0)) + _
         " DT ___________(___) COMMA _______(____) COMMA _______(____)(.) 'R' OF AS ASKED VIDE OUR LETTER UNDER REF IS STILL AWAITED (.) REQUEST FWD THE SAME BY _______ (___) (.) "

    t1.Rows(6).Cells.Merge
    t1.Rows(6).Cells(1).Range.Text = String(116, "-")

    t1.Rows(7).Cells(1).Split NumRows:=1, NumColumns:=2
    t1.Rows(7).Cells(1).Range.Text = "XYZ"
    t1.Rows(7).Cells(2).Range.Text = "TELE:27676455"
    t1.Rows(7).Cells(3).Range.Text = "SR MGR"

    t1.Rows(8).Cells(1).Range.Text = "CASE NO: " + UCase(objVar(0))
    t1.Rows(8).Cells(2).Range.Text = "EXEC"

    t1.Rows(9).Cells(1).Range.Text = "DATED: " + UCase(Date)
    t1.Rows(9).Cells(2).Range.Text = "TOR____H"

End Sub
```